# Intuition of Standard and Analytic Borel space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

An analytic Borel space is a countably generated Borel space which is the image of standard Borel space under a Borel mapping. A [standard Borel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space) is the Borel space associated to a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space).

What is the intuition of standard and analytic Borel space? And some examples, please.

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Analytic_Borel_space might help.